# Hibernate unable to delete parent/child self-join entity

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, parent-child, cascade

I'm trying to delete a parent/child self-join entity  but unable to do so
here is my mapping

```java
@Entity
public class FolderNode  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "hibernate_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "hibernate_sequence", sequenceName = "hibernate_sequence")
    @Column(name="folder_id")
    private long folderId;

    
    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    @OnDelete(action = org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private FolderNode parent;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For correct parent/child relation modeling you should have modeled the one to many part of relation please find an example:

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Menu parent;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Menu> children = new ArrayList<Menu>();
```

This is an unidirectional link so the owner of the relation would be the parent side of the relation. Now when you issue a `EM.delete(parent)` or `session.delete(parent)` the `delete` will be cascaded by the chain and children will be deleted too ( normally called orphans, by default hibernate will not issue a delete statement on orphans ) so that's why `orphanRemoval = true` is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Though bit old to answer, but today i faced same issue, but on deleting child, parent is also getting deleted.

Do not use `cascade={CascadeType.ALL}` on Parent if you do wish to cascade CRUD operations from child to parent.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
private Menu parent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Menu> children = new ArrayList<Menu>();
```

If you delete children, it also deletes the parent: you can remove cascade operations from parent.

So we can change as per below,

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
private Menu parent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Menu> children = new ArrayList<Menu>();
```